# How to call a hive UDF written in Java using Pyspark from Hive Context

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I use `getLastProcessedVal2` UDF in hive to get the latest partitions from table. This UDF is written in java . I would like to use the same UDF from pyspark using hive context.

```
dfsql_sel_nxt_batch_id_ini=sqlContext.sql(''' select l4_xxxx_seee.**getLastProcessedVal2**("/data/l4/work/hive/l4__stge/proctl_stg","APP_AMLMKTE_L1","L1_AMLMKT_MDWE","TRE_EXTION","2.1")''')
```

Error:

> ERROR exec.FunctionRegistry: Unable to load UDF class:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Answer (score 1):

start your `pyspark` shell as:

`pyspark --jars /path/to.udf.jar <all-other-param>`

OR

submit your pyspark job with `--jars` option as:

`spark-submit --jars /path/to/udf.jar <all-other-param>`

Answer (score -1):

You could register that user defined function using [SQLContext](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.html) method [udf](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.html#udf()), there you can see that you have to pass a string as the first parameter and it will represent the name of your `udf` while using `SQL` queries.

e.g.

```java
sqlContext.udf().register("slen",
       (String arg1) -> arg1.length(),
       DataTypes.IntegerType);

sqlContext.sql("SELECT slen(name) FROM user").show();
```